# Edit form data before submiting to ASP.NET mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method/controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] RoleViewModel roleVM)
```

and I have many-to-many relationship between Roles and Privileges, and need to post role privileges to the method, so I changed the method by adding Privileges to the binding:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Privileges")] RoleViewModel roleVM)
```

the role privileges are displayed using jstree control, I have the privileges in Javascript array:

```
var arr = $('#tvPrivileges').jstree(false).get_checked();

        var filledArr = new Array();

        arr.forEach(fillPrivileges)
        { }

        function fillPrivileges(item, index) {

            var privilege = {
                Id: item,
                Name: ""
            }

            filledArr.push(privilege);
        }
```

Role and Privilege models:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel()
    {
        this.Privileges = new List<PrivilegeViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public  List<PrivilegeViewModel> Privileges { get; set; }

}


public class PrivilegeViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; 

}
```

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RolesController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RoleForm" }))
            {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, Resources.Captions.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Privileges, Resources.Captions.Privileges, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="tvPrivileges"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="@Resources.Captions.Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Captions.Cancel, "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-white"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

How can I add the privileges to the model before submitting the form?

Comment: Are you sure that you *added another parameter*?  It looks like to me that you simply added `Privileges` to the binding of a `RoleViewModel` object

Comment: *How can I add the privileges to the model before submitting the form?* Well the methods that you posted are for `[HttpPost]` which means that the only way those privileges will be added is when you do actually submit.. so are you asking how to do this on the `[HttpGet]`?

Comment: Sorry I meant I added the Privileges to the binding. I want to add the privileges and submit them using POST

Comment: Is `Privileges` a property of your ViewModel `RoleViewModel`?

Comment: @Samirovic tough to know for sure without seeing what you're posting and what your model looks like. You might make sure that the input names being posted have an index value of some sort. [1],[2],[3]... That should help the binder pick  it up. IE: privilege[1].Id, privilege[2].Id, etc

Comment: Yes the Privileges (List<Privilege>) is a property of RoleViewModel

Comment: First, your using a view model (at least the name of the class suggests it is) so remove the `[Bind]` attribute (you never need that when using a view model). Are you submitting this via ajax? And what are your models? You need to show the relevant code and how your posting to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a string property PrivilegesRaw to hold the privileges:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel()
    {
        this.Privileges = new List<PrivilegeViewModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public  List<PrivilegeViewModel> Privileges { get; set; }

    public  string PrivilegesRaw { get; set; }

}
```

And added this line in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PrivilegesRaw, new { @id = "hdnPrivileges" })
```

And filled the privileges inside the hidden field before submitting:

```
    function BindPrivilegesToModel() {
    var arr = $('#tvPrivileges').jstree(false).get_checked();
    document.getElementById("hdnPrivileges").value = arr.join(',');
}

$(function () {
    $("#RoleForm").submit(function () { BindPrivilegesToModel(); });
})
```